# sql query to count number of users based on event sequence

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called test which is sorted by time.

```
 user_id  event      time
    1       e1         t1
    1       e3         t2
    1       e2         t3
    2       e2         t4
    2       e1         t5
    2       e5         t6
    3       e2         t7
    3       e4         t8
```

I have to find out how many unique user_id is there in which event e1 happens before e2. here the answer is `one` with user_id 1.

I am using postgresql.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably your solution, with a sub-select of events where `ev2`:

```
WITH event(user_id,event,time) AS (
      VALUES (1,'e1','t1'),
             (1,'e3','t2'),
             (1,'e2','t3'),
             (2,'e2','t4'),
             (2,'e1','t5'),
             (2,'e5','t6'),
             (3,'e2','t7'),
             (3,'e4','t8'))
SELECT count(event.event) FROM event
JOIN (SELECT user_id, time
FROM event WHERE event = 'e2') AS ev2 ON event.user_id = ev2.user_id
WHERE event.time < ev2.time AND event.event = 'e1'
```

Filter all rows before `ev2` takes place and the value should be equal to `ev1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.user_id, 
       Count(e.event) 
FROM   event e 
       join(SELECT user_id, 
                   TIME 
            FROM   event 
            WHERE  event = 'e2') AS ee 
         ON e.user_id = ee.user_id 
WHERE  e.TIME < ee.TIME 
       AND e.event = 'e1' 
GROUP  BY e.user_id
```